# Exclude Column of a certain table in JOOQ code generation?

Tags: java, maven-plugin, jooq

How can I exclude a column in a certain table with JOQQ code generation?
I have in maven the part of the "jooq-codegen-maven" plugin:

```
                <database>
                    <name>org.jooq.meta.mysql.MySQLDatabase</name>
                    <inputSchema>fishes</inputSchema>
                    <includeExcludeColumns>true</includeExcludeColumns>
                    <includes>.*</includes>
                    <excludes>users.type|users.mark</excludes>

                </database>
```

However, that doesn't work. Leaving out "users.", it will work but then the columns will be ignored in all tables, and that is not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to either fully qualify an object or not qualify it at all. So, write:

```
<excludes>fishes\.users\.(type|mark)</excludes>
```

Comment: Cool, it works, but do you know where I can find that in the documentation as it wasn't clear to me.

Comment: @edbras: Here https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-includes-excludes *"These expressions match any of the following object types, either by their fully qualified names (catalog.schema.object_name), or by their names only (object_name)"*